# calculating the end of a decade

Tags: php

What is the simplest way of calculating the "next" decade given the year as a string?  For example:

```
"2011" -> "2020"
"2012" -> "2020"
"2013" -> "2020"
 ...
"2020" -> "2020"
"2021" -> "2030"
 ... etc.
```

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: try to find the next number which is divisible by 10.

Comment: As trivial a question as this may seem to some - It's funny how varied the answers are.  The psychology of programming and how people approach problem-solving is quite interesting.  I voted up because it's the simplest questions that highlight this.

Comment: Is 2020 the last year of the 10's decade, or is it the first year of the 20's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$date = '2013';
echo ceil($date/10)*10;
```

Comment: I like this, it's short and works! Thank you @Emissary for such a quick and elegant solution.

Comment: It think to be precise of what we call a decade, it needs to be using floor() instead of ceil(). Cause ceil() will produce a decade ahead if you give to it a year or 1996 for example, it will produce 2000 where the correct decade should be 1990.

Answer (score 5):

Try this one:

```
$endOfDecade = $year - ( $year % 10 ) + ($year % 10 ? 10 : 0);
```

The last part takes care of the last-in-decade year.

Answer (score 2):

Just try with:

```
$year = 2013;
$endOfDecade = $year - ( $year % 10 ) + 10;
```

Comment: This will not work if $year is already last year in the decade.  For $year=2020 you'll get 2030.

Comment: If we`re on 2020, we`re starting new decade, so the end of decade is 2030.

Comment: Wrong.  A decade runs from 1/1/2011 to 31/12/2020 and from 1/1/2021 to 31/12/2030.  If you're in the middle of 2020, the decade ends in 2020.

Comment: @AleksG: I think it depends.  If we talk about "the 1990s", we generally mean 1990-1999, inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $x = date('Y'); 
    while($x % 10 !=0)
    {
        $x++;
    }
    echo $x;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$year=2013;

 $decade=$year+((($year%10)>0)?(10-($year%10)):0);
 echo $decade;

?>
```

Comment: This will not work if $year is already last year in the decade. For $year=2020 you'll get 2030.

Comment: @ Aleks ,Now it is ok?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the most elegant solution, that would not be an appropriate question for SO, but here is an algoritm to solve your problem:

```
$year = 2013;
$end = $year + (10 - $year%10)
```

Comment: This will not work if $year is already last year in the decade. For $year=2020 you'll get 2030.